# Using a published Watt-hour power curve for AA batteries, I get a theoretical battery life that's way lower than in practice

Tags: batteries

I'm doing something wrong mathematically. Can anyone spot my mistake?

I'm powering some laser sensors and an arduino with 8 AA batteries and a step-up box for the lasers. I calculated a theoretical battery life using some empirical Watt-hour findings for my batteries here: http://rightbattery.com/57-1-5v-aa-duracell-procell-alkaline-battery-tests/

Both I and the source website used a cutoff point of 1V per cell. My cutoff point was 8V.

I first used their Wh values and plotted them out as in the attached image. Then I found an exponential approximation, input a measured current draw, and got an answer for my theoretical Wh (see bottom right of image under "Dual laser test setup (no LCD, Xbee)".

Then I divided the Wh by Watts, which is the measured system voltage times the measured current and got 0.169 hours which is 10 minutes. I ran a test though, and it took 85 minutes to reach 8V, starting from 11.7 with 8 batteries. There seems to be some discrepancy.

The batteries lasted 8 times longer than predicted! But I was under the impression that for batteries in series, you don't add the mAh, since the current through each battery is the same, as described here:  [Adding mAh when wiring battery cells in series?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/20701/adding-mah-when-wiring-battery-cells-in-series)

So what gives?

[image: See Screengrab Here]

Comment: Did you account for the fact that you're calculating Wh per battery and using 8 batteries?

Comment: As I referenced, I was under the impression that for batteries in series, you don't add the mAh, since the current through each battery is the same. The link to that discussion is here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/20701/adding-mah-when-wiring-battery-cells-in-series

Comment: Right but your "Watts" calculation incorporates the voltage from 8 cells not 1. You are then dividing the Wh rating  *for a single cell* by this power to get time, and wondering why the time is 8* smaller than measured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brian Drummond (see comments) is correct.  For each battery that you have:

$$Power = V_{batt}I_{batt}$$

---

If you put the batteries in parallel, your voltage doesn't change, but your potential current changes:

$$Power = V_{batt}(8I_{batt})$$

---

If you put the batteries in series, your potential current doesn't change, but your voltage does:

$$Power = (8V_{batt})I_{batt}$$

---

Either way, you get 8x the Power with 8 batteries:

$$Power = 8V_{batt}I_{batt}$$

---

Add in the *time* factor and you have Amp-hours or Watt-hours.

Comment: No problem, I worked through similar pain on a project a few months back (looking at your spreadsheet).  As it happens, at low current draws, you can typically predict within about 10% the life of a product given its discharge curve.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Your discrepancy comes from the failure to account for the capacity of the 8 cells. Your presumption of not using the collective total is wrong when talking about watts or watt hours but correct when considering amp hours or total amps.

Answer (score 0):

Two things, the manufactirers usually publishna guaranteed capacity (some will be higher), second, the capacity can be quite dependent on how fast you drain them, a clock might get 2-3Ah from a AA while a high power flashlight might only 1Ah. As a side note, Dave Jones from the eeVblog found you could get an extra 10% just by squashing them a bit so their capacities have quite wide margins